# Increase leeway of click event on a control WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I have a click event on my Line control, which opens up a context menu. The way I've had to set the lines up means you don't get a lot of leeway in terms of where you have to click for the context menu to appear, so I'm wondering whether there's a way to increase the 'radius' that's allowed for the control so that it will fire the click event even if it's slightly off the line control itself. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would `padding` help?

Comment: You could draw another thicker line on top of your line and make it transparent and handle its click event instead. Set `IsHitTestVisible` property of your original line to `false`.

Comment: @Stefan I don't think the Line Control has a Padding property unfortunately.

Comment: @rashmatash Good idea, I'd rather not render anything more than I need to though honestly as the program is already taking a while to boot up due to how many components I'm having to render. This is definitely something I'll try if I can't think of another solution though, cheers. - EDIT, there's a lot of instances where I'm having to apply this so it's not just a one time thing.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You could handle the `PreviewMouseDown` event on the parent of your `Lines` and then do hit testing using an "expanded hit area"....and see if you get an intersection with any of your lines.

You could also do it by surrounding your line with another element such as the `Grid`.

Here's some sample code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="348" Width="483" PreviewMouseDown="Window_PreviewMouseDown">
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Line x:Name="line1" X1="0" Y1="10" X2="200" Y2="10" Stroke="Yellow" StrokeThickness="20" Width="200" Height="20" Tag="yellow"/>
        <Line x:Name="line2" X1="0" Y1="10" X2="200" Y2="10" Stroke="Red" StrokeThickness="20" Width="200" Height="20" Tag="#red"/>
        <Line x:Name="line3" X1="0" Y1="10" X2="200" Y2="10" Stroke="Green" StrokeThickness="20" Width="200" Height="20" Tag="#green"/>
        <Line x:Name="line4" X1="0" Y1="10" X2="200" Y2="10" Stroke="Blue" StrokeThickness="20" Width="200" Height="20" Tag="#blue"/>
        <Line x:Name="line5" X1="10" Y1="20" X2="180" Y2="20" Stroke="Cyan" StrokeThickness="20" Width="200" Height="40" Tag="cyan" MouseDown="Line_MouseDown"/>
        <Line x:Name="line6" X1="10" Y1="20" X2="180" Y2="20" Stroke="Magenta" StrokeThickness="20" Width="200" Height="40" Tag="magenta" MouseDown="Line_MouseDown"/>
        <Grid Width="200" Height="40" MouseDown="Grid_MouseDown" Background="Transparent">
            <Line x:Name="line7" X1="10" Y1="10" X2="180" Y2="10" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="20" Width="200" Height="20" Tag="black" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        ContextMenu m_menu = new ContextMenu();
        Line m_hitline = null;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            m_menu.Items.Add("hit");
            m_menu.Items.Add("MenuItem1");
            m_menu.Items.Add("MenuItem2");
        }

        private void Window_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Line linehit = null;

            Point pthit = e.GetPosition((UIElement)sender);

            HitTestResult htresult = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(this, pthit);
            linehit = htresult.VisualHit as Line;

            if (linehit == null)
            {
                // Expand the hit test area by creating a geometry centered on the hit test point.
                //
                // You could use a RectangleGeometry if you like....or even something more complicated

                EllipseGeometry expandedHitTestArea = new EllipseGeometry(pthit, 5.0, 5.0);

                m_hitline = null;

                // Set up a callback to receive the hit test result enumeration.
                VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(this, null,
                    new HitTestResultCallback(MyHitTestResultCallback),
                    new GeometryHitTestParameters(expandedHitTestArea));

                linehit = m_hitline;
            }

            if (linehit != null)
            {
                // mouse hit directly on line so show context menu for it
                m_menu.Items[0] = "hit " + linehit.Tag;

                m_menu.IsOpen = true;
            }
        }

        public HitTestResultBehavior MyHitTestResultCallback(HitTestResult result)
        {
            // Retrieve the results of the hit test.
            IntersectionDetail intersectionDetail = ((GeometryHitTestResult)result).IntersectionDetail;

            switch (intersectionDetail)
            {
                case IntersectionDetail.FullyContains:
                case IntersectionDetail.FullyInside:
                case IntersectionDetail.Intersects:

                    Line linethatinterestedwithhitarea = result.VisualHit as Line;

                    // We ignore testing against none-line visuals (you may or may not want to do that)
                    //
                    // We will only do expanded hit testing against "lines" that have set a tag beginning with #

                    if (linethatinterestedwithhitarea != null)
                    {
                        // We will skip "expanded" hit testing on lines that have no Tag set
                        // i.e. the Yellow lines - just shows one way to "control" which lines you want
                        // to test against....you could also compare against a predefined list of lines
                        // you know you want to add this behaviour to.

                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(linethatinterestedwithhitarea.Tag.ToString()) && linethatinterestedwithhitarea.Tag.ToString().StartsWith("#"))
                        { 
                            m_hitline = linethatinterestedwithhitarea;

                            return HitTestResultBehavior.Stop;
                        }
                    }

                    return HitTestResultBehavior.Continue;

                default:
                    return HitTestResultBehavior.Stop;
            }
        }

        private void Line_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Line linehit = sender as Line;

            if (linehit != null)
            {
                m_menu.Items[0] = "hit " + linehit.Tag;

                m_menu.IsOpen = true;
            }
        }

        private void Grid_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            m_menu.Items[0] = "hit black";

            m_menu.IsOpen = true;
        }
    }
}
```